# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word saveas2 and save using vb.net gets Command failed

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

I continually get "Command Fail" at either the saveas, saveas2 or save calls when trying to save a new programmatically created `.docx`. I know that the file is being created. works fine offline.
Visual Studio 2013
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 15
Microsoft Office 10 on server and dev machine
test code:

```
myInfo_lbl.Text = ""
Dim word As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
word.Visible = True
Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
doc = word.Documents.Add()
Try
    Dim insertText As String = "This thing needs to start fn working. Damn it!"
Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range = doc.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
range.Text = insertText
doc.SaveAs2("D:\myCVCOL_Files\test2.doc")
'doc.Save()
'doc.SaveAs2("D:\myCVCOL_Files\test2.doc")
Catch ex As COMException
    myInfo_lbl.Text = ex.ErrorCode & " ~ " & ex.HResult & " ~ " & ex.Message & " ~  try 6"
Finally
    Dim save_changes As Object = False
    doc.Close(save_changes)
    word.Quit(save_changes)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't set the format.  Try this code

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        CreateDoc()
    End Sub

    Public Sub CreateDoc()
        Dim wordApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
        Dim wordDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
        Dim range As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range
        Dim fileName As String
        Dim insertText As String

        Dim format As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocument

        wordApp = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
        wordDoc = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document()
        insertText = "Some text"

        wordApp.Visible = True

        fileName = "D:\Projects\Sandbox\StackOverflow\ConsoleVB\test2.doc"

        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

        range = wordDoc.Range(Start:=0, End:=0)
        range.Text = insertText

        wordDoc.SaveAs2(fileName, Format)

        wordDoc.Close(Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
        wordDoc = Nothing
        wordApp = Nothing

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but am still getting the error. The more I mess with this, the more I think it is a setting on the server, iis or word.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the solution to my problem that I was searching for2 days for was a setting in Word.
Found it at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53a0aa18-5f26-4a51-95c8-5c0ff9be28f4/command-failed-at-microsoftofficeinteropworddocumentclasssaveas?forum=vsto

"I faced this problem before and I googled it for two days and finally I found the solution that go to Run Command dcomcnfg.exe Or Go to Component Service Then you have to choose DCOM Config and choose Microsoft Word and get properties of it and in identity Tab choose  the interactive User instead of the launching user."

Answer (score 0):

I had for many months an 80% error when converting a word to a pdf using the `function  SaveAs(WordDocFilePath & WordDocName & ".pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)` in VB.NET 2013 in a Windows 10 environment. I tried many things but this very simple change resolved just everything :

WordApp.ScreenUpdating = False (whether it was true before)